# Answers collapsed under the questions on the FAQs page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a FAQs page (pure HTML). The questions have css class .pageSubtitle and the answers  have two classes: .p1 and .p2. The example is:

```
<p class="pageSubtitle">Which Award should I apply for?</p>
<p class="p1">Centers that wish to be recognized for adhering to Guidelines and their Quality Programs and their Processes should apply for <span style="font-weight: bold;">The Center of Excellence in Life Support Award.</span> 
These programs must meet or exceed criteria in the following categories:
</p>

<p class="p2">o Systems Focus</p>
<p class="p2">o Environmental Focus</p>
<p class="p2">o Workforce Focus</p>
<p class="p2">o Knowledge Management</p>
<p class="p2">o Quality Focus</p>
<p class="p2">o Process Optimization</p>
<p class="p2">o Family Focus</p>
```

On this FAQ page, the users want to have the answers collapsed under the questions and when you click on a question the answer appears under it. How can I do that? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: add another hidden div below class p2 and when the div is hover display it a block using JavaScript or jquery

Comment: Thank you for your interest and help. But I am very new in jquery and js. Can you add some code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution that works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.p1, .p2, .p3, .p4').hide(); 
$('.pageSubtitle').click(function(){ 
$(this).nextUntil('.pageSubtitle').toggle();
 }); 
 }); </script>
```